# problem with using to_date in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date

i simply wanna change a string to a date format using to_date 
`SELECT TO_DATE('20-APR-20 09.50.06 AM' , 'DD-MOM-YY HH24:MI:SS AM') FROM DUAL;`

and also i want to change to 24 format

when i run this i get the ORA-01821: date format not recognized error .

Comment: Should be `DD-MON-YY . . .`

Comment: In addition to the other comments -- always, always, always use 4-digit years, not 2-digit.  Does the term 'Y2k bug' ring any bells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct format for converting your string to a *date* is:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('20-APR-20 09.50.06 AM' , 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM')
FROM DUAL;
```

If you want it as a string, then you can use `TO_CHAR()` after converting to a date.  That said, I recommend keeping the value as a date.

Answer (score 1):

The correct format is

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20/APR/20 09.50.06 AM' , 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS AM'),'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS AM') FROM DUAL;
```